# deployed shiny app behaves differently in different browsers (uploading csv)

Tags: r, csv, cross-browser, shiny, uploading

I have an app in which it is required to upload a **`.csv` file**. I have the following code to prevent uploading files of other formats.

```
filedata <- reactive({
infile <- input$datafile
if (is.null(infile)) {
  # User has not uploaded a file yet
  return(NULL)
}
if(infile$type != "text/csv" && infile$type != "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain"){
  # User has uploaded wrong format
  return("error1")
}
read.csv(infile$datapath)
})

output$some.element <- renderUI({
latest_quarter.raw <- filedata()
if(is.null(file.raw)){
  return(wellPanel("No file uploaded "))
}
if(file.raw=="error1"){
  return(wellPanel("Upload a *.CSV "))
}
...
})
```

The script when run in IE or MS Edge or Chrome doesn't allow to upload `.csv` or any other file (`.xlsx`,`.xlsb`, etc) with the error `"Upload a *.CSV"`, however, works perfectly fine (as it is supposed to) in Mozilla Firefox.
This is a very strange problem that I'm facing and a very troublesome one too. Any pointers as to how to implement this kind of error handling while allowing smooth running in the mentioned browsers will be appreciated very much. Thanks

Comment: Did you check the value of `infile$type` when you upload the file with the other browsers? I would guess that different browsers might report different content types. There's nothing really magical about `csv` files. They are just plain test file. And you can have CSV data in files that end with any extension. You should make sure that test is really necessary.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, it helped. Apparently I was too baffled by the problem to think clearly about it :P